# Parse tokenized c code using java

Tags: java, c, parsing, compiler-construction, tokenize

I have split the C code into tokens.

For example

`void main()
{
     int a=10;
}`

Converted code

```
void
main
{
int
a
=
10
;
}
```

I identified types of tokens. Now i want to parse the tokens. Do i have any Java API to do that, else please suggest some tutorials with practical examples.

Comment: Parsing C-like code is surprisingly difficult since its grammar is not context-free. This is a somewhat broad question, but your main options would be using a parser generator or writing a recursive descent parser yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ANTLR, it's very good and it has a C grammar: http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html

Comment: Piokuc, it has grammar but I asked for parser to parse the code with the grammar. I am ready to write my own parser but don't know how to write!

Comment: Antlr can use the grammar (something a human programmer wrote) to generate automatically a parser in Java (or in few other languages). If you really want to write a parser by hand, google for 'recursive descent parser tutorial', read it, understand it and go for it, but it's going to be a lot of work, really.